# how to use unity android plugin array parameter?

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine

array parameter send error.
Please help me.

C#

```
    activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>{
        plugin = new AndroidJavaObject(CLASS_NAME);
    }));

    public void Func(List<string> list){
      plugin.Call("Func",new object[]{list})
    }
```

jar

```
    public void Func(List<String> list){
      Log.d("test","in");
    }
```

Error

```
Exception: JNI: Unknown signature for type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' (obj = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]) instance
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending an array of one element: a list of string, perhaps you wanted to send and an array of string?

Change

```
plugin.Call("Func",new object[]{list})
```

to

```
plugin.Call("Func", list.ToArray());
```

Comment: So, an array of array of string? Try `plugin.Call("Func", new object[] {list.ToArray()});`.

Comment: sorry, this try:AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError